# Wordpress: is_ios() function not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been trying to use the is_ios() function but it doesn't seem to work. Once the page is compiled where I put my php code using the is_ios() it becomes blank.

This is the footer portion of a Wordpress document.

```
<?php if ( is_ios() ) : ?>
    <a href="instagram://user?username=USERNAME">
<?php else : ?>
   <a href="http://www.instagram.com/USERNAME">
<?php endif; ?>
<i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

If I were to change `<?php if ( is_ios() ) : ?>` to `<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) : ?>` the code would run fine.

I'm not sure if I need to include something or anything. After looking at the docs for it (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/is_ios/) I checked to see if the function existed in the correct place and it did. I don't know what else to try. Any insight or help would be appreciated.

**FULL CODE**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
 ?>

<footer class="footer text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <p><strong>
        <i class="fa fa-copyright" aria-hidden="true"></i> USERNAME 
        </strong> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
        <a href="https://twitter.com/USERNAME"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> 
        <?php if ( is_ios() ) : ?>
            <a href="instagram://user?username=USERNAME">
        <?php else : ?>
            <a href="http://www.instagram.com/USERNAME">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </p>

    </div>
  </footer>
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your logs for the error details (or turn on error reporting). From the doc you linked, it looks like it's part of a class `WP_Customize_Manager::is_ios()`, so you're not calling it correctly.

Comment: @ceejayoz turned on error reporting (cool stuff) and checked out the stack trace. `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_ios()` so I tried changing `is_ios()` inside the function to `WP_Customize_Manager::is_ios()` and got a new error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Customize_Manager' not found`. So I think I need to import the class somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_ios` is a method of `WP_Customize_Manager` class. So you need to first create an instance:

```
<?php 

include_once('wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php');

$customizeManager = new WP_Customize_Manager();

if ( $customizeManager->is_ios() ) : // etc. ?>
```

Otherwise you can just copy the whole code:

```
<?php if ( wp_is_mobile() && preg_match( '/iPad|iPod|iPhone/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ) : // etc. ?>
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much. With `$customizeManager->is_ios()` is that how you use a method inside of a class with PHP?

Comment: Actually it's quite an overkill to create an instance of this class just for using one method. This class is really meant to be used for the customizer in the admin side. It's also safer to copy the whole code... I'd do this way.